# Queries to the database return empty or null but saving data does work

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a web API using ASP.net MVC core with Entity Framework Core. i'm using NSwag to use swagger documentation and Swagger UI, there I'm testing the Post methods and they work, but the get returns empty or null.

here you can see the data in the database

[image]

the code to get all the data of a table is this:

```
 // GET: api/UserRoles
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<UserRole> GetUserRoles()
        {
            return _context.UserRoles.ToList();
        }
```

but it returns null even when there is data on the database, and all other queries return null or empty (or throw an exception in the case of `.First()`

this is my `OnModelCreating`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //Debugger.Launch();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasOne(x => x.ParentCategory).WithMany(x => x.SubCategories).HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCategoryId);

        foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var type = entity.ClrType.GetInterface(nameof(Interfaces.IDto));
            if (type == null) continue;
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).Property<DateTime?>("DeletedAt");
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType)
                .Property<DateTime>("LastUpdated")
                .HasComputedColumnSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()");
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType)
                .Property<DateTime>("CreatedAt").HasDefaultValueSql("SYSUTCDATETIME()"); ;
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType)
                .HasKey(nameof(Interfaces.IDto.Id)).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType)
                .HasIndex("CreatedAt").ForSqlServerIsClustered();


            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entity.ClrType, "e");
            var body = Expression.NotEqual(
                Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { typeof(DateTime?) }, parameter, Expression.Constant("DeletedAt")),
                Expression.Constant(null));
            modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter));

        }

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasIndex(x => x.Identification).IsUnique();
    }
```

this is my `UserRole` model

```
public class UserRole:Dbo
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

this is my `Dbo` class

```
public abstract class Dto : IDto, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

all the queries return null or empty for all models

Update:

here you can see a `Where()` method being called with 0 results (i have only one record with `name` being equal to "admin"), also you can see that querying the `StockMovementFlow` table being queried and return 0 records too.

[image]

Comment: show how is USerRoles mapped (even if it is a  dbml generated EF)

Comment: @Gonzalo.- updated

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the right database? Check _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString in the running code

Comment: Im pretty sure because the writes on this database context are written to the database beign shown also i have created a test that reads the db and then writes on it, the read is null or empty but the write succeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `Expression.NotEqual` here:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entity.ClrType, "e");
var body = Expression.NotEqual(
    Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { typeof(DateTime?) }, parameter, Expression.Constant("DeletedAt")),
    Expression.Constant(null));
modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter));
```

What is does currently is to set a [global query filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) (i.e. additional condition applied to *all* queries) similar to this (pseudo code):

```
e => e.DeletedAt != null
```

which would return all soft deleted records (which in your case are none), while I guess the idea was to return non soft deleted records, i.e.

```
e => e.DeletedAt == null
```

So simply change `Expression.NotEqual` to `Expression.Equal` and the issue will be solved.

Comment: I love you dude! you are right i was implementing the filer in a bad way...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a query to get specific info from your context.

create the query to your table using the context.

Eg.

```
var query = context.Students
                   .where(s => s.StudentName == "Bill")
                   .FirstOrDefault<Student>();
```

query.tolist()

Comment: I have tried other methods, find(), Where(), first(), all the same

Comment: also that `.AnyAsync()` inside the `if` returns `false`

Comment: have you tried getting data from your context outside of the seed function? Where are you calling this function?

Comment: yes, I have tried getting data directly on the controllers (UserRolesController, StockMovementFlowController, etc) and same result

Comment: In your table the name is not admin it is administrador, change this in your where statement?

Comment: Admin is not visible, but is there, I have already tried with Administrador, and with x.Name!=""